# XSP4 could not start, missing xsp4 assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mono, xsp, slackware

I have a mono (**2.10.7**) instance running and I'm trying to code some **ASP.NET MVC 3** application but I just hit a wall I don't know how to pass.

First, I was getting an error about XSP4 not being found (launching a simple app from MonoDevelop **2.9.1 Beta**), so I installed XSP from the Git repo (with the default options) and, after that, trying to launch the server, I get a missing reference pointing to Mono.WebServer v0.4.0.

I looked in the web for the Mono.WebServer DLL, found it, download it and put it into the GAC, and now I getting this errox64

```
Handling exception type FileNotFoundException
Message is Could not load file or assembly 'xsp4, Version=2.11.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of 
its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So now I don't really know what I'm missing (I just installed **xsp4**!).

I'm running **Slackware x64 13.37** and all Mono packages but **xsp4** (that got from the Git repo), am I missing something? could be that something is in the wrong place?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. To correct, I added xsp4.exe, and Mono.WebServer2.dll Mono.Security.dll to the gac:

```
gacutil / i xsp4.exe
gacutil / i Mono.WebServer2.dll
gacutil / i Mono.Security.dll
```

Comment: `Failure adding assembly Mono.WebServer2.dll to the cache: The file specified is not a valid assembly.`

Comment: For me, this command removes xsp4.exe from the gac directory and now all the symlinks to it point nowhere. Not sure what's causing this behavior but proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find the other mono packages? I think error is because xsp from git requires mono from git. Try getting package xsp2 from same place or compile mono from git also.